# Custom decomposition tree in Vega/Vega Lite

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, vega, deneb

Has anyone tried creating a custom decomposition tree visualization in VEGA/VEGA Lite? So each branch of the visual would be customizable, allowing for custom labels, variances, charts, etc. – something similar to a decomposition tree consisting of Power BI new KPI card visuals.

While creating a KPI card is easy, I'm struggling to transform it into a decomposition tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? If so, the full code (too long to paste here) can be found: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase
[image]

Comment: thank you for this, I try to play around with it a little bit :)

Comment: Could you please help? Formatting to my needs works fine from the sample provided, and this is really cool, I have to say. However, what I'm struggling with is that my data source is a PBI dataset and not a JSON file. If I understood correctly, the first line in the JSON (Max Armstrong) is the basis for the rest of the tree. How can I replicate this structure in a PBI dataset? My goal is to achieve a format similar to the one demonstrated in the sample file here : https://github.com/tomecsek21/pbix_file. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is more of a power query problem now. Can you post another question with the details and either myself or someone else will help get the data in the right shape for you.