# Decomposition tree sample visual fitting

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega-lite, vega, deneb

Here is a sample [provided by](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78101506/3001761) Davide Bacci:

[image: Text]

I would like to use this template for my .pbix file; however, it's not working as expected. In Davide's example, the datasource is a JSON, whereas I have a Power BI dataset. I need to replicate a similar structure, especially the first line (Max Armstrong), to make it work.

Here is a sample of my data structure:
https://github.com/tomecsek21/pbix_file

The visual should begin with a node representing total revenues, and then it should be divided into sublevels. Nodes should always be sorted based on revenues, from highest to lowest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple roots and a tree works from a single root. To keep this simple, rename your columns as follows:

[image]

Add them to a Deneb visual but put a filter on so you only see a single root:

[image]

In the spec, overwrite source with the following:

```
 {
  "name": "dataset"
},
{
  "name": "source",
   "source": "dataset"
},
```

Change the domain to the following (my kpis were percentages hence the hard coded 0-100):

```
{
      "name": "kpiscale",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": [0, 1800],
      "range": {"signal": "[0,scaledNodeWidth]"}
    },
```

[image]

That should be enough for you to restructure your data but if you add more levels, you will need to update the Vega.

Comment: Sorry, I was out this week! For some uses cases it will do the job but for this particular one I probably need to remake the Vega..so that the tree starts with a total, aggregated rectangle which is then broken down into pieces...thank you for your time and willingness!